# CIFS VFS: error -22 updating the kernel

Tags: kernel, updates

The following error is output to / var / log / syslog every time after rebooting after updating the kernel.
"CIFS VFS: error -22 on ioctl to get interface list"
The following updates have been made.
4.15.0-1013-azure → 5.0.0-1031-azure
Please tell me the cause and solution.

Comment: "`perror 22`" gives "`OS error code  22:  Invalid argument`", read `man ioctl`, re-examine `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

MS Support has responded to this error, and despite the response that the server side does not support SMB files that are not supported by Azure Files called SMB multichannel, the Linux Kernel further calls ioctl and Therefore, it turned out that this occurred because the server returned an error.

Reference: Features not supported in Azure Files
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/features-not-supported-by-the-azure-file-service